# RequestDispatcher Showing Page's source code Java Servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

Everything is working fine else **why RequestDispatcher showing source code of page?**

```
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String uName=req.getParameter("uEmail");
        String uPass=req.getParameter("uPass");
        try{
            DBConnection con=new DBConnection();
            if(con.login(uName, uPass)){
                HttpSession on = req.getSession();
                on.setAttribute("u_id", uName);
                res.sendRedirect("dashboard.jsp");
            }
            else{
                RequestDispatcher dis= getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/login.jsp");
                PrintWriter write = res.getWriter();
                write.println("Wrong Username or Passowrd");
                dis.include(req, res);
            }
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e){}

    }
}
```

Page redirecting fine to given url `/login.jsp` and also showing the error message, but why as source code?

```
Wrong Username or Passowrd

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="LoginServlet" method="POST" />
            <input type="text" name="uEmail" />
            <br /><br />
            <input type="text" name="uPass" />
            <br /><br />
            <input type="Submit" name="Register" value="Register" />
            <br /><br />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

direct link to `login.jsp` works fine.

Comment: Because you have "Wrong Username or Passowrd" printed before the html tag, making the HTML invalid?

Comment: @JBNizet how to use Dispatcher then? I'm using on other testing application that works fine even same dispatcher code.

Comment: What you have is fine, except you shouldn't write text to the response before inclusing the JSP. By doing that, you're generating invalid HTML. Store the error message in a request attribute, and have your JSP code get it from that attribute and print it, where it must be printed, inside the page. There is no reason to include: you should forward instead.

Comment: @JBNizet I'm confused why other applications works fine with same process?

Comment: @JBNizet thanks those was on `login.html` that's why they works fine?

Comment: All answers here are wrong. Observable problem is caused by using `write.println("Wrong Username or Passowrd");`. Abovelinked duplicate shows correct way how to generate HTML response using servlet and how to set and display messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from  http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#include(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse)

The include method of Request Dispatcher gets the content of the resource that why you are getting the source code in browser.

I think what you want to do is forward the request to login.jsp so use forward method of request dispatcher.

As @JBNizet mentioned in his comment due to your message from Servlet, HTML is going to be invalid.

Comment: As linked javadoc states, `RequestDispatcher.include` still should execute jsp instead of showing it's source: http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/12/11/requestdispatcher-include-method/

Answer (score 2):

before `dis.include(req,res);` 
add this line `res.setContentType("text/html);` it

Comment: You should add a bit of explanation around why what you suggest will fix the issue, etc. etc.

Comment: By default MIME(aka Content-Type) is set to "text/plain" you have to change according to your file(or your content) you want to show on the client(browser).

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue when I used RequestDispacther method and try to return and String massage along with html page then i have found you have to put some kind of tag to the String massage like

then use include method
so if my code was

```
out.println("Terms & Condition not accepted");
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.html");
rd.include(request, response);
```

i changed it to "

```
out.println("<h1>Terms & Conditions not accepted </h1>")
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.html");
            rd.include(request, response);
```

"

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the content type of the response.

Add the below line in your `doPost` method.

```
response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
```

Hope it works for you!!

Answer (score 0):

set content type for the response
response.setContentType("text/html");